# Change netmask (but not ip) of network interface

Tags: ifconfig, netmask

The `ifconfig` command can change both the ip address and netmask of a network interface:

```
ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Is it possible to change the netmask of the network interface `eth0` without knowing (and changing) it's ip address?

I've tried

```
ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but I get the error

```
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Invalid argument
```

Comment: "...with a script" "...on OS X"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just specify the same IP address as currently configured with the new subnet mask to the `ifconfig` command.

```
ifconfig eth0 `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | tr -s " " | cut -f 3 -d " " | cut -f 2 -d ":"` netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(That makes me feel dirty...)

Edit:

Having said that, on an old-as-heck Fedora Core 2 box (the oldest box I could find on short notice) I am seeing `ifconfig` working fine to set the netmask w/o setting the IP. What version of net-tools are you looking at?

Comment: The point is that I will not know the IP beforehand. I'm doing these specific configurations programmatically, and having to first fetch the IP address is a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the IP is, just

> ifconfig eth0

and it will be displayed. Then you can use that in your configuration command.

Comment: The point is that I will not know the IP beforehand. I'm doing these specific configurations programmatically, and having to first fetch the IP address is a hassle.

Comment: @randomblue actually "ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0" works fine for me on Debian. What OS is this?

Comment: I'm using OS X.

Comment: I don't have an OS X box handy but here's the man page: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html address should be an optional argument. Maybe try "ifconfig eth0 inet netmask 255.255.255.0"?

Answer (score -1):

ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up its should work fine